# recebendo valores do usuário que não sejam números repetidos

Tags: array, algoritmo

Bom dia!

sou iniciante em algoritmo e estou fazendo uma algoritmo que recebe do usuário  um vetor de 20 posições inteiras com valores entre 1 e 20, só que não podem existir número repetidos e nem menor que 1 ao maior que 20. A minha dúvida é como fazer essas condições rodar..quem puder me ajudar agradeço muito.abaixo segue o que eu fiz

Algoritmo "semnome"

```
Var

valores: vetor[1..20] de inteiro
i,num: inteiro

Inicio

para i de 1 ate 20faca

 escreva("informe um valor:")
 leia(num)
 valores[i] <- num
fimpara


escreval("================================== ")
para i de 1 ate 20 faca
   escreva(" ")
   escreva("o elementos do vetor são:",valores[i])
   escreval(" ")
   escreval(" ")
fimpara
Fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisará utilizar utilizar o "se" e um vetor auxiliar. Basta utilizar um vetor booleano de 20 posições, de modo que o seu i-ésimo valor indica se o número i já foi lido ou não.

```
var 
valores: vetor[1..20] de inteiro
numeroJaFoiUsado: vetor[1..20] de booleano
i, num: inteiro

Inicio

para i de 1 ate 20 faca:
    numeroJaFoiUsado[i] = false
fimpara

para i de 1 ate 20 faca:
    escreva("Informe um valor: ")
    leia(num)
    
    // Não queremos usar o número se ele está fora dos limites.
    se numero < 1 ou numero > 20
        continue
    fimse 

    // Não queremos usar esse número se ele já foi usado.
    se numeroJaFoiUsado[num]:
        continue
    fimse

    // Se a execução chegou até aqui, é pq o número está ok.
    valores[i] = num

    // Lembre de marcar como usado, pra não usá-lo novamente!
    numeroJaFoiUsado[num] = true
fimpara
```

Observações:

- numeroJaFoiUsado[num] é a mesma coisa do que fazer numeroJaFoiUsado[num] == true, só que mais conciso.
- continue pula para a próxima execução do laço para, ou seja: volta para o início do fluxo de execução do para, só que na próxima iteração. Sua utilização não é obrigatória, mas uma questão de gosto pessoal. Você poderia obter o mesmo comportamento usando apenas se/se não, apenas utilizando condições diferentes.
- Note que se o usuário inserir os números erroneamente, algumas posições do vetor não serão preenchidas.